# Server Token Not found

Tags: uber-api

This is a simple question.I am beginner to Asp .Net core.

After registering my app I redirect to Uber developer dashboard .Where I got Client_id,Client_secret.And

**Server token** not found there .It  indicate

> Please reach out to your Uber Business Development representative for
> server token access.

And also I am unable to select scope

> Genrel or  Privileged

How can I solve this problem

And also I need  **.Net core SDK** as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should select which sdks you need, [here](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks)